# How to disable swipe to delete icon in listview

Tags: android

I am using swipe to delete in list view from git hub (https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidSwipeLayout) lib . I want  to disable swipe to delete icon how can i achieve this ?.

```
swipeLayout.addSwipeListener(new SimpleSwipeListener() {
              @Override
              public void onOpen(SwipeLayout layout) {
                  YoYo.with(Techniques.Tada).duration(500).delay(100).playOn(layout.findViewById(R.id.trash));
              }
          });
```

Comment: You have to make changes in lib

Comment: @ Himani , no need, there is option in there lib..